# Enable to find all data in date range 7 days ago in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date-range

I want the count of my table data having in date range 7 days before from now. So I have tried this query :

```
SELECT DATE(leads_update_on), IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) leads 
    FROM tbl_leads 
    WHERE project_id=4 
    AND DATE(leads_update_on) >= DATE_SUB('2016-05-11', INTERVAL 6 DAY) 
    GROUP BY DATE(leads_update_on)
```

But it returns following result :

```
       `DATE(leads_update_on)|leads
       ----------------------|-----
       2016-05-06            |    7
       2016-05-07            |    4`
```

Since other dates does not have any data but I want the result like below if there is no data in specific date :

```
       `DATE(leads_update_on)|leads
       ----------------------|-----
       2016-05-05            |    0
       2016-05-06            |    7
       2016-05-07            |    4
       2016-05-08            |    0
       2016-05-09            |    0
       2016-05-10            |    0
       2016-05-11            |    0`
```

What I have to change in my sql query so that I can find the above result. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Sample Input as requested :

```
    `DATE                |id
   ----------------------|-----
   2016-05-06            |    1
   2016-05-07            |    2
```

Here only two data is present so for others dates it should return 0 value. It should output like this :

```
       `DATE(date)           |leads
       ----------------------|-----
       2016-05-05            |    0
       2016-05-06            |    1
       2016-05-07            |    1
       2016-05-08            |    0
       2016-05-09            |    0
       2016-05-10            |    0
       2016-05-11            |    0`
```

But using this query :-

```
SELECT DATE(`date`), IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) leads FROM test where DATE(`date`) >= DATE_SUB('2016-05-11', INTERVAL 6 DAY) GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

It returns below result which **I don't want**:

```
       `DATE(date)           |leads
       ----------------------|-----
       2016-05-06            |    1
       2016-05-07            |    1`
```

Comment: Here's a writeup of a solution to this problem. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand you need to change your `if null`condition

**Updated**

```
select distinct(res.leadDate), res.leads from        
(select mon.aDate as leadDate , ifnull(sa.leads, 0) as leads
  from (
     select '2016-05-11' - interval (a.a ) day as aDate from
     (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
     union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all
     select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) a
 ) mon
 left join tbl_leads sa on mon.aDate = sa.leads_date ) res, tbl_leads ss
 where res.leadDate between ss.leads_date and '2016-05-11'
 order by res.leadDate asc;
```

Comment: I have given the expected output what i want, If some dates does not have value then count should be zero. Your query return data :- `DATE(leads_update_on)|leads
       ----------------------|-----
       2016-05-06            |    0
       2016-05-07            |    0`

Comment: can you post sample input data?

Comment: please see my updated question I have put sample input. Please note it is just a sample not a exact input

Comment: please see updated question

Comment: Its not producing the result as expected, it produce only one row

Comment: check your table names, I had used dummy names to test the query. Suggest you to run the query in parts to understand